# how to speed up tshark processing / reporting

Tags: libpcap, tshark

As tshark version 2.0.0, If I run a network throughput speed test like speedtest over a 50Mbps down/up link, tshark will stay "forever" dequeueing and digesting packets to be able to report at the stdout. tcpdump doesn't appear to suffer from any major overhead (tho I had to increase buffer size to avoid dropping packets for tcpdump).

After several attempts to tweak tshark, like increasing buffer size, avoiding writing pkts to tmp ( I tried `/dev/null` - no option for it, `/run/out1.tmpfs`, etc), `-n -Tfields` (showing only a few fields), tshark failed to report > 20Mbps in realtime. I wonder if there's any technique that I can use to improve its processing capacity. Thank you.

I still need some of the tshark features like the tcp retransmission analysis (afaik `tcpdump` doesn't do much stuff other than dumping packets).

Comment: Could you add the full tshark and tcpdump commands you've tested to your question? In particular, do you have a capture filter? Also, how did you measure tcpdump and tshark's writing speeds?